# ArrayList's indexOf() returns -1 in java

Tags: java, list, comparison, return-value, indexof

I'm validating my List of data's from file with the data's in the database to avoid duplicate insertion in database,if duplicate exists then i want the index of that record in file,am using the below code,

```
List<StudentMaster> studentMasterListFromDB = studentMasterDao.getStudentList();
List<StudentMasterVO> studentMasterListFromFile = getStudentMasterListFromFile();

for(int index=0;index<studentMasterListFromDB.size();index++){
    StudentMasterVO studentMasVO = new StudentMasterVO();
    StudentMaster studentMaster = studentMasterListFromDB.get(index);       
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(studentMasVO, studentMaster);      
    int indexOfexistingRec = studentMasterListFromFile.indexOf(studentMasVO);
    System.out.println("indexOfexistingRec :"+indexOfexistingRec);


}
```

But "indexOfexistingRec" value is giving -1,not the index of the existing record index.

Comment: `-1` suggests that the item you were looking for wasn't found.

Comment: Thanks for reply.In my list the searching record is there,but it is showing -1.

Comment: sorry,that is BeanUtils.copyProperties() method.

Comment: Manually incrementing index lead to crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement `hashCode` and `equals` methods in your `StudentMaster` and `StudentMasterVO` classes so that they will be properly compared for equality.

If you are using Eclipse (or any other IDE), then it can generate those methods for you, just choose which fields are to be taken into account when comparing.

See for example this article if you are not familiar with the concept: http://www.javaworld.com/community/node/1006

Comment: Thanks for reply,i have already used equals() and hashcode() for StudentMaster and StudentMasterVO.But am still having the same problem.Even i have checked the hashcodes also,hashcodes are also coming correctly.

Comment: So, what does copyProperties do?

Comment: Its a BeanUtils method,just copying the value of one object into anthoer object,here from StudentMaster Object to StudentMasterVO Object.But i think that is not at all the problem.

Comment: If your classes implement hashcode and equals correctly, and if object equal to that you are searching really _is_ on the list, then there is no reason for it not to work.

Comment: Maybe you are calling your copyProperties with wrong order of arguments.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and reply.While checking instanceOf(),i used wrong object.That is what the problem is. :)